# AMPScript encoded link mangled by Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

```
Concat("https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=", URLEncode(Concat("http://company.com/page?item=", itemid)))
```

The URLEncoded question mark is being replaced by an ampersand. Is there a way to stop that without rewriting our item page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://company.com/page?item=%%=v(itemid)=%%">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: An alternative would be to break it down in several blocks:
%%[
SET @Link1 = ...., SET @ Link2 = ...., SET @ EndLink = Concat(@ Link1, @ Link2)
]%%